# I have set of jobs record for whole month and want to display qty of jobs date wise in SQL

Tags: sql

We have thousands of record in our data and want to count date wise jobs with category through single query. It is Possible?
Display required as under

```
TypesJobs   01  02  03 04 05 06 07        
A            2  1    6  4  1  3  4
B            10 12   8  10 12 9  13
C            3   5   4   3  2  5  4
```

Here Types of jobs count for a day in date column 01, 02, 03 are date range of the month

Comment: Google for "pivot query SQL".

Comment: If you're using MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation, something like this:

```
select typesjobs,
       sum(case when month(datecol) = 1 then 1 els e0 end) as month_01,
       sum(case when month(datecol) = 2 then 1 els e0 end) as month_02,
       . . .
from t
where <date condition here>
group by typesjobs;
```